# Iteration: sum of variable and vector front, export in another vector, erase vector front

Tags: c++, vector, sum, iteration, erase

I am dealing with my first ever code and I am blocked again on a new problem.

I have a bunch of values in a vectorA, and I want to perform the following **while** loop (in pseudo-code) :

"Make a variable *double* **SUM = 0** and a variable *int* **count**.

Take the **front** value of the vector, add it to **SUM**"

Then erase the **front** value in the vector

The variable **SUM** should act as a capacitor: when **SUM** is superior to a given constant **u**,

SUM becomes equal to **SUM - u**

Another vector **vectorB** would store the value of **count** each time **SUM > u**

Right now I only have a VectorA that contains all my values and an export of the list into a .txt file.

I would like to find a way to put the front value of vectorA in a local variable to add it to SUM, and then erase this front value.
Is that possible? Are there better ways to do this?

Here's the code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

// constant values

float Da=0.1; //densities
float Db=0.5;
float Dc=1;
double Dd=0.333333;

int l = 10;  //width & height
int h = 10;

float u = 10;  // UNIT

int main ()
{
    // vectors
    vector <double> VectorA;
    vector <double> vectorB;
    int I = 0;              //itération pour la somme des valeurs du vecteur
    double SUM = 0;         //somme des éléments du vecteurA

    float a = 0;
    float b = 0; // Local variables

    while (a<l+1, b<h+1){
        //values for given a & b

        double DL = Da-Da*(b/h)+Dc*(b/h);
        double DR = Db-Db*(b/h)+Dd*(b/h);
        double D  = DL-DL*(a/l)+DR*(a/l);

        //print
        //cout<<D<<endl;

        //store
        VectorA.push_back (D);

        // next pixel/unit & next line
        a = a+u;

        if (a>l) {
            a = 0;
            b = b+u;
        }
    }

    // export values to .txt file
    ofstream output_file("./step1.txt");
    ostream_iterator<double> output_iterator(output_file, "\n");
    copy(VectorA.begin(), VectorA.end(), output_iterator);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's make this a bit simpler by taking out all the domain-specific stuff, and just discuss the basic question:

> [How do I] put the front value of vectorA in a local variable to add
>   it to SUM, and then erase this front value?

Here is a simple approach:

```
vector <double> vectorA;
double SUM = 0.0;
// ...

while (!vectorA.empty())
{
  const double curVal = vectorA.front();  // this strictly isn't necesarry.  the compiler might optimize this away
  SUM += curVal;
  vectorA.erase (vectorA.begin());
}
```

Now let's incorporate `u`:

```
vector <double> vectorA;
double SUM = 0.0;
const double u = /* ??? */;

// ...

while (!vectorA.empty())
{
  const int curVal = vectorA.front();  // this strictly isn't necesarry.  the compiler might optimize this away
  if (curVal > SUM)
  {
    SUM = curVal - u;
  }

  vectorA.erase (vectorA.begin());
}
```

I'm not really sure how `count` acts, or what values are being stored in to `vectorB`, but as a wild guess I'm going to assume that `count` is incremented every time `curVal > SUM`, and the resulting new value for `count` is inserted in to `vectorB`.  So let's try to implement that:

```
vector <double> vectorA;
double SUM = 0.0;
const double u = /* ??? */;
int count = 0;
vector <int> vectorB;

// ...

while (!vectorA.empty())
{
  const int curVal = vectorA.front();  // this strictly isn't necesarry.  the compiler might optimize this away
  if (curVal > SUM)
  {
    SUM = curVal - u;
  ++count;
  vectorB.push_back (count);
  }

  vectorA.erase (vectorA.begin());
}
```

There are opportunities for micro-optimization above, but recall Knuth's golden rule:

> Micro-optimization is the root of all evil.

When building software, the best approach is to first select the correct algorithm with needed efficiency in mind (be they space or time efficiency) and build that in a robust, easily maintaned way.  Then profile your program in a Release build, identify problem hotspots, and micro-optimize those sections of the code only where necesarry.  If you select the correct algorithm to begin with, and write it well, you'll often find that no micro-optimization is needed.

Comment: Sorry but what are myInts, myVals and curVal?

Comment: Sorry bout that.  `myInts` was supposed to be your `vectorA`, and then I changed it to `myVals`, but missed a few.  I'll change them all to `vectorA`.

Comment: @adrienlucca.wordpress.com: There, I hope that makes a bit more sense now.

Comment: How `count` acts well... `count` is an `int` that "rounds" on a grid the position when SUM > u , so the function of `count` is to mark these moments on each line of a width `l`

Comment: Thanks, however I don't get what happens now, I only get `1` as output of vectorB

Comment: I rewrote it like that, but there's still a problem... `while (!vectorA.empty())
{
  int curVal = SUM + vectorA.front();  // this strictly isn't necesarry.  the compiler might optimize this away
  if (curVal > u)
  {
    SUM = curVal - u;
  vectorB.push_back (cou);
  cou = 0;
  }
  else {
    SUM = curVal;
    cou++;
  }


  vectorA.erase (vectorA.begin());`